# Keep real numbers in Ruby language

Tags: ruby

How are real numbers kept in Ruby language? How can I keep 7.125 as real number in the memory? In this code:

```
myNumber = 7.125
puts("The number is #{myNumber}")
```

I do not understand how the number is kept in memory.

Comment: [From the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Float.html): *"Float objects represent inexact real numbers using the native architecture's double-precision floating point representation."*. There is no way to access it directly from the language's API. But why do you need that anyway?

Comment: that's a question in exam in university.

Comment: Maybe the entire point of Ruby is that you should *not* have to think about these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby `1.8` & `1.9`, floats are never immediates, so all floats require a new memory allocation.

In Ruby `2.0.0`, on `64 bit` systems, many floats [are now immediate](http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2013/02/23/ruby-2-by-example/#optimizations). This means that the typical floats don't require memory allocation & deallocation anymore, so much faster operations.

Ruby stores its values in a pointer (`32` or `64` bits, depending on the platform). It actually uses a trick to store immediates in that pointer. This is the reason why Fixnum can only hold 31 / 63 bits.

On 32 bit platforms, there's no clever way to store floats, but on 64 bits platforms, it's possible to use the first ones to flag this value as an immediate float and the remaining 60 or so to hold the data. The floats that do require the full 64 bits can not be immediates, though, so these are stored like before using an actual pointer.

More info on this optimization can be found in the https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6763

Comment: This is too general. The OP wants to know particularly about real numbers (or floats, according to ndn's interpretation).

Comment: I don't see how `Fixnum` is relevant.

Comment: @sawa : Thanks to clear my misunderstanding of OP's question. I hope now it's relevant answer or should I delete?

Comment: so 1 bit for pointer, others for numbers?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to keep real numbers in Ruby. The closest things are `Float` or `Rational`, both of which cannot express real numbers fully.

Comment: `Float` and `Rational` are in Fixnum class? so my answer "7.125 can be hold in fixnum class and memory use 1 bit for point, other bits for numbers"

Answer (score 0):

How about the `Bigdecimal` class (arbitrary precision arithmetics)? See the [API](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html), which follows standards on the topic.